# Is Istio a “must” in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, istio

We are trying to re-architect our Microservices and move them into Docker containers. We are going to use Kubernetes to orchestrate Containers. We have made some investigations on how should we use different technologies in combination with Kubernetes among others Istio to have the best of everything:-).

However the more we read on Internet, the more we become confused. We know that Kubernetes has ingress and “ingress controller” and to our understanding Istio maybe is better when it comes to inter-service communication and it addresses among others service discovery and circuit breaker challenges. But we don’t know if we can address all these problems by using only Kubernetes ingress?

1. Why and when should (should not) you use Istio with  Kubernetes?
2. Why and when should you use ingress controller?

Thanks

Comment: You can probably do what you want with "plain" Kubernetes. You can research Kubernetes "Service" objects for discovery (not ingress). ISTIO adds extra routing features and also security on top of Kubernetes.

Comment: that's probably too broad of a question for stackoverflow, but generally it's just like you already mentioned, if you got a lot of inter-service communication and routing within your cluster, istio might be better suited than plain kubernetes. if you have autonomous microservices in the original sense that simply serve stuff behind some application gateway (ingress controller), istio is only adding unnecessary overhead and complexity. simple inter-service communication can always be achieved with some message queue like rabbitmq, kafka and the like.

Comment: Thanks;

We have two type of inter-service kommunikations direct and indirect. We are considering to use Kafka for indirect communication (covering eventual consistency). However for direct communication between services we have some dificulties to choose right technology.

Comment: @user217648 "Istio" is not a must, but a service mesh is, in my opinion, a way to go and definitely needs to be implemented when it comes to production. My personal favorite, therefore, is [linkerd](https://linkerd.io/2/overview/) as it is faster the istio, easier to configure and does everything you need. most projects do not require traffic management or so. Check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing the questions:

1. If you need [advanced network features](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/), such as advanced routing, circuit breaking, weighted deployments, encryption, etc., then is best to pick Istio. For "*simpler*" needs, where you only want to container orchestration, you can stick with Kubernetes only.
2. Ingress controller determines the behavior of the [Ingress object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), which in turn is used to expose the applications running within the cluster. This means that, each ingress controller has a different set of options/features, generally tied to layer 7 operations. [Whenver you're exposing your applications via Ingress, you're using an ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

Now, it is implied that the ingress controller *may* do thing like service discovery or circuit breaking. This is not the case. These features are addressed by the [Service Mesh](https://www.nginx.com/blog/what-is-a-service-mesh/) (Istio is one product that creates one within the cluster) and the goal of the Ingress object is to expose and often do some routing the services within the cluster.

You can think of Ingress as a gateway, allowing incoming connections in the cluster, path-based routing and SSL-termination. So it's basically running as an access point, whereas Istio will be running *within* the internal network, managing connections between the services without exposing them (although it can through ingressgateway), and adding a set of advanced routing features in the internal network.

Comment: Thanks Yahir, 
Is it possible to have different setups for different projects inside same Kubernetes cluster? because maybe in a project we have services that call each other quite often, but in another project services do not need to call each other directly but indirectly then we can use a Message broker or Service Bus. or in a project we don't need to use either a Service Mesh or Message Broker because services are autonomouse, so in this case it is enough to have only Kubernetes ingress? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Specifically for Istio and thanks to how it was designed, you can limit the `Service Mesh` to specific namespaces (via [sidecar injection](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/)); this way, is possible to have an Istio-based cluster alongside the "vanilla" Kubernetes version.

Comment: With Sidecar injection means that we are not going to use Istio as ingress but as sidecar? Is there any more sources that we can read?

Comment: Istio is a group of features and objects that include a sidecar (refer to the "service mesh" link in the answer) and can also include their own implementation of an ingress-like object called [ingressgateway](https://blog.jayway.com/2018/10/22/understanding-istio-ingress-gateway-in-kubernetes/), different from an ingress object (reference in the answer). You **must** use the sidecar in order to create the service mesh and additionally, you can deploy an Istio-based ingress to expose it. These Istio objects can coexist with conventional k8s objects in the same cluster via namespace injection.

Comment: 1-If I understand your comment correctly, I need to have Sidecar AND Istio ingressgateway to have a functionall Service Mesh functionality? 2-If I use Istio Ingressgateway, do I still need Kuberenetes Ingress? One more question :-) 3-if we have already a API Gateaway like Azure API Management or APIgee, do we still need one of above ingresses (Isito or Kubernetes)?

Comment: 1. Ingressgateway is used to expose services running in the mesh, so if your definition of functional is also publicy exposed, then yes. 2. Ingressgw only works with the service mesh, namespaces where there's no Istio mesh it needs their own ingress 3. Not sure about Azure, but for Apigee, you need your cluster exposed somehow to ingest. Note that this in particular may vary depending on the [Apigee pattern](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/patterns-for-deploying-kubernetes-apis-at-scale-with-apigee#deployment_options_for_apigee_edge) used

Answer (score 1):

My short answer in my opinion is no, Istio is not a "must" in a Kubernetes cluster.

In one of the migration projects I have worked, there was already a centralized governance/control and observability. So the requirement didn't include Istio.

But, nevertheless, we had a Proof-of-Concept to evaluate which features Istio has better/worse versus our setup. [Local setup](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/getting-started/) of everything is possible with a [Docker Desktop](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/docker/) and a [local K8s cluster](http://collabnix.com/kubernetes-dashboard-on-docker-desktop-for-windows-2-0-0-3-in-2-minutes/).

If you assess that the microservices setup you have does not have a good inter-connectivity, governance, observability that Istio has to offer, I suggest to give it an effort to try out with a couple of your applications even just locally. You will see actual pro's and con's.